# record visibilty vs record level access

Tags: security, sharing

What are the difference between these? In the Sharing and Visibility Designer certificate exam guide it says:

> Articulate different security capabilities with respect to record visibility, CRUD based security, record level access and the differences between the three.

I know CRUD based security relates to if a user can create, read, update, and delete records from an object. But there appears to be too much subtlety between a user having "visibilitiy" or "access" when it relates to a record.

Comment: I have that certification, and I think that's just sloppy wording. I don't see that either of those terms is well-defined enough in the context to be clearly making a distinction between, for example Role- and Sharing Rule-based visibility on the one hand and some other area like Territory Management or Communities or Content sharing on the other.

Comment: It is accurate, however, to say that the certification covers many different techniques for managing record-level access.

Comment: I wonder if the author perhaps meant to refer to that last item as "field level access" instead?